# is there a way to make HTML, CSS , JS static page a wordpress dashboard so that the user can change the content images

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a landing page using HTML, CSS , and JavaScript which are the tolls I am familiar with, but the client informed me that he want a dashboard to update the contents , images ...etc . I am not familiar with WordPress and have not done any project before. So is there any way to create the website then convert it into WP or any other way to solve the issue I am facing ?

hope I found a solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create the HTML first. Then you can convert it to a WordPress Theme. But would require some [PHP coding](https://www.w3schools.com/php/) and [knowledge in WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/) template structure, functions, etc.

Or else, you can hire a developer for this purpose.

Or the more easier way for you would be to use a drag and drop content creation plugin like [Elementor](https://elementor.com/) (personally, I like it more) or [WPBakery](https://wpbakery.com/) or something else.

**EDIT:**

To answer your question in comment, there's a starter theme called [Hello](https://elementor.com/hello-theme/). You can use it as your canvas and start adding your components and layouts in it. There are many third party Elementor addons available for use (some are premium). I mean certain elements for your layout would already be there as an addon widget created by someone else or it might be already shipped with the Elementor plugin!

If you have some time to spare (I mean it's not an urgent project), I would suggest some time playing with it.

Comment: thank you for your comment, the problem that i have to follow a design that the client provided me with , so for the Elementor i think that i have to active a theme then customize this theme by Elementor , and i think (not sure) i can not follow the exact. design , am I right?

Comment: thank you for your respond, I actually will have to create a page slimier to existing page just i have to add section and change in CSS , what do you think the best way to get the existing page and customize it. knowing that the existing page is a WordPress already and can be edited with Elementor

Comment: What I would suggest is, create a new blank page. Then use the Elementor to create the content by copy pasting text from the existing page. You won't be able to directly convert the existing page into an Elementor page with a single click. There are many widgets in Elementor which you can make use of to create the page the way you want!

Comment: first of all thank you for your response i really appreciate it. its conformed that the page is created using PHP coding and then it will be uploaded to WordPress (Zip it then uploaded it , Which i am not sure how) , my work is to change the hero section and body section only with different contents and design CSS totally different. My question is  when i get the source code i will change it then uploaded it as a theme , is it possible to use this theme without affecting the existing theme? and so you have any experience in this ? thank You

Comment: To upload a WordPress theme, you have to zip the theme folder and upload it in Appearance - - > Themes in admin panel. Regarding making changes and re uploading the theme, I would suggest using a FTP client and upload the files to the location: `/wp-content/themes/your_theme_name_here/` replacing the existing the theme files with the updated files. Please go through the folder structure of wordpress to get an idea. I already shared the link in my answer.

Comment: this WordPress has 2 themes (one is the main theme (ACTIVE) that has 5 pages & Second theme (NOT ACTIVE) that has ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) linked to it as the front page) multi theme plugin is use for the second theme to work.

Now I have another theme (third theme) that I want to create ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) for it and I will use the multi theme plug in as well. the problem that when I change the reading setting of the second (theme) page all content disappears.

how can I add ACF to multiple themes that installed in one WordPress?